# How to generate beautiful bird coding in latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Can somebody help[image] how to get this image in latex coding only?

Comment: latex is probably the wrongest tool for this. Do it in inkscape and export to tikz

Comment: what's wrong with `\includegraphics{bird}` ?

Comment: I want to know how to have coding in latex without \includegraphics{bird} to get the desire output. Using tikz etc.

Comment: "Help" ≠ "Please do it for me". So what have you tried? (Of course you may get lucky and someone will do it for you.)

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but asking LaTeX to produce the output you generated is equivalent to asking to some image editing program to produce a beautifully typeset book: it may be able to do it (you will have to draw each and every line of the text) but it's clearly not what it's meant to do; I deem it a purposeless task.

Comment: `I want to know how to have coding in latex without \includegraphics{bird} to get the desire output. Using tikz etc.` I don't think @DavidCarlisle was unclear what you were asking. The question is, why in the Milky Way would you form such a desire in the first place?

Comment: If you were mad enough to insist on doing it in LaTeX directly, Ti*k*Z would be just about the worst drawing package to use. MetaPost would be better. Not a good choice, but a less awful one. (I suppose the new Ti*k*Z calligraphy package might be able to do it, though.)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think this looks almost the same.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (10,10) circle (1)
      (11,10) -- (11.5,10.5) --(10.8,10.5)
      (10.3,10.3) circle (.2)
      (10.7,10.7) circle (.2)
      (9.3,9.3) -- (3,3) edge[bend right] (9.3,9.3)
      (7,7) -- (9,11) -- (8,11) -- (7,7)
      (7,7) -- (5,10) -- (4,9) -- (7,7)
      (7,5.5) -- (7,0)
      (7,5.5) -- (9,2);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, the difference is hardly recognizable ;-)

Comment: Not quite as good as David might have done with `picture` mode, but definitely worth an upvote, nonetheless.

Comment: This reminds me of those strange fonts with birds in. Do you know the ones I mean?

Comment: @cfr didn't you [look in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36367678#36367678) ????

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Occasionally .... I don't read the entire transcript ;).