# How to generate the image shown below?

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

Can somebody try to generate such type of image using LaTeX coding only.

Please give the explanation of the codes so that we can understand it.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) of what you've tried so far. Moreover, do you want to use it like an image or like a comma?

Comment: Why do you insist in trying to use `LaTeX` for [these tasks](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361067/how-to-generate-beautiful-bird-coding-in-latex) when there exist programs (Inkscape, Gimp, even Paint) which are designed for them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you think of something like this?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \fill[black!80] (-90:1cm) arc (-90:90:1cm)
    to [controls={+(180:2.2cm) and +(180:2.5cm)}] (295:3.5cm)
    -- ++(0,0.1) to [controls={+(180:0.5cm) and +(270:1cm)}] (-90:1cm);
 \fill[red] (0,0) circle (0.6cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Mr Jurgen can you explain the coding so that we may understand it and in future we can also help to others people problem. thank you so much once again.

Comment: Please have a look into the tikz manual. The main aspect here is the macro which begins with `\fill[black!80]`. There you can modify the values inside the `control`-blocks to fine tune the form of the comma.

Answer (score 6):

Since you have posted 5 questions, all without any mwe, for the explanation please make at least the effort to search for the commands in the TikZ-PGF manual!

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    pics/mycomma/.style             = {code={%
            \node[scale=20,xscale=-1]{,};
            \node[very thick,red,circle,text width=.1cm,fill=red] at (-.02,.7) {};
        }},
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
            \pic {mycomma};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is a very nice idea. Chapeau!